# Cross Tab Query with Records Going Horizontally | MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Essentially I have created a cross tab query, but I need some help presenting more of the records horizontally.

I have reviewed some of the pointers from the following post to progress forward, but still need some help, I would really appreciate a bit more help to get this final part correct.

[How can I Create a Multi-Value CrossTab Query in Access 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752147/how-can-i-create-a-multi-value-crosstab-query-in-access-2013)

**I currently have a table with the following data:**

[image]

**Using the following Query I was able to get all the colours to display horizontally with no issue:**

```
TRANSFORM First(ColourNames.AssignedColour) AS whatever
SELECT ColourNames.ProductID
FROM (SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.[AssignedColour], "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*),"000") AS ColourName FROM ProductColor AS t1 INNER JOIN ProductColor AS t2 ON (t1.[AssignedColour]>=t2.[AssignedColour]) AND (t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID) GROUP BY t1.ProductID, t1.[AssignedColour])  AS ColourNames
GROUP BY ColourNames.ProductID
PIVOT ColourNames.ColourName;
```

**Result:**

[image]

**But I am having some trouble understanding how I can also list the ColorFinding Horizontally after each AssignedColour for each ProductID like this:**

[image]

---

---

**2nd Attempt:**

**CrossTab Query 1:**

```
TRANSFORM First(ColourNames.AssignedColour) AS whatever
SELECT ColourNames.ProductID
FROM (SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.[AssignedColour], "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*),"000") AS ColourName FROM ProductColor AS t1 INNER JOIN ProductColor AS t2 ON (t1.[AssignedColour]>=t2.[AssignedColour]) AND (t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID) GROUP BY t1.ProductID, t1.[AssignedColour])  AS ColourNames
GROUP BY ColourNames.ProductID
PIVOT ColourNames.ColourName;
```

**CrossTab Query 2:**

```
TRANSFORM First(ColourNames.ColourFinding) AS whatever
SELECT ColourNames.ProductID
FROM (SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.[ColourFinding], "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*),"000_Finding") AS ColourName FROM ProductColor AS t1 INNER JOIN ProductColor AS t2 ON (t1.[ColourFinding]>=t2.[ColourFinding]) AND (t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID) GROUP BY t1.ProductID, t1.[ColourFinding])  AS ColourNames
GROUP BY ColourNames.ProductID
PIVOT ColourNames.ColourName;
```

How can I now combine the results of the 2 to get the needed result?

---

---

**Update 2:**

I am getting incorrect results using the Nested Subquery Approach:

```
SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.[AssignedColour] AS Data, "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*),"000") AS Cnt
FROM ProductColor AS t1 INNER JOIN ProductColor AS t2 ON (t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID) AND (t1.[AssignedColour]>=t2.[AssignedColour])
GROUP BY T1.ProductID, T1.AssignedColour
UNION SELECT t1.ProductID, t1.[ColourFinding], "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*),"000") & "_Finding"
FROM ProductColor AS t1 INNER JOIN ProductColor AS t2 ON (t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID) AND (t1.[ColourFinding]>=t2.[ColourFinding])
GROUP BY T1.ProductID, T1.ColourFinding;
```

**If following is my data:**
[image]

**My Expected Result is:**

[image]

**Using the Nested  Sub Query I get the following:**
[image]

Comment: I am sure you already asked this question. Did you delete it? Also referred you to http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues. Exactly what do you not understand about guidelines in those links?

Comment: I was able to fix nested query but then the CROSSTAB won't work with it so I removed it from my answer. Sorry, Access just does not deal well with row numbering in query.

Comment: Revised answer again.

Comment: @June7 I appreciate your help, I really learned a lot

Comment: @June7 Can you please take a look at my recent question, it’s more of a general question that relates to MS Access Queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple techniques described in referenced links:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues
[How can I Create a Multi-Value CrossTab Query in Access 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752147/how-can-i-create-a-multi-value-crosstab-query-in-access-2013)

Join your two CROSSTAB queries to Products - master table of unique product records. Pull fields into query in whatever order you want.

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, ProductName, Colour001, Colour002, Colour003, Colour001_Finding, Colour002_Finding, Colour003_Finding
FROM Query2 RIGHT JOIN (Query1 RIGHT JOIN Products ON Query1.ProductID = Products.ProductID) ON Query2.ProductID = Products.ProductID;
```

That does limit to 3 sets of data. So use wildcard to pull in fields but then cannot specify order.
`SELECT Products.ProductID, ProductName, Query1.*, Query2.* ...`

Another approach involves a UNION query that would then be used in CROSSSTAB. This is quite likely the slowest performance approach.

Query1: DataUNION

```
SELECT ID, ProductID, AssignedColour AS D, "Assigned" AS Cat, "Colour" & DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID='" & ProductID & "' AND ID<" & ID)+1 AS GrpSeq FROM ProductColor
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, ColourFinding, "Finding", "Colour" & DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID='" & ProductID & "' AND ID<" & ID)+1 & "_Finding" FROM ProductColor;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM First(DataUNION.D) AS FirstOfD
SELECT DataUNION.ProductID
FROM DataUNION
GROUP BY DataUNION.ProductID
PIVOT DataUNION.GrpSeq;
```

Here is what I have for UNION with nested queries to generate row numbering. Unfortunately, CROSSTAB doesn't like it. So, final suggestion is to write these records to a temp table and use that table as source for CROSSTAB.

```
SELECT ProductID, [AssignedColour] AS Data, (SELECT "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*)+1,"000")
FROM ProductColor AS T1 WHERE ProductColor.ProductID = T1.ProductID AND ProductColor.[ID]>T1.[ID]) AS GrpSeq
FROM ProductColor
UNION SELECT ProductID, [ColourFinding] AS Data, (SELECT "Colour" & Format(COUNT(*)+1,"000_Finding")
FROM ProductColor AS T1 WHERE ProductColor.ProductID = T1.ProductID AND ProductColor.[ID]>T1.[ID]) AS GrpSeq
FROM ProductColor;
```

VBA code like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM ProductColorTEMP"
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO ProductColorTEMP SELECT * FROM DataUNION"
```

Comment: My apologies I forgot to include in example table that ProductID is actually ShortText not a Number field, when using your Query1 I get a DataType Mismatch. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Just as an example ProductID actually looks like: A1,A2,A3

Comment: Then use apostrophe delimiters for text parameter. Revised answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this method is indeed very slow. Can you please show an example of the multi-value cross tab query? I am having some trouble following that explanation

Comment: The guidelines provided are quite clear to me. Exactly what do you not understand? Build two CROSSTAB queries. Build another query joining those queries to Products table.

Comment: Please see my updated post, I posted the 2 needed queries, I just cannot seem to understand how to properly combine the results of the 2 within a third cross tab query. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: It's not a third CROSSTAB, it's just a normal query joining 2 CROSSTAB queries to a table. This presumes you have a Products table. Revised answer.

Comment: The only issue I have with doing a SELECT query and pulling in the column order manually is currently there maybe 3 Colors (meaning 3 Sets of Colour00# and Colour00#_Finding) but at some point there could be more, the select query will not anticipate more than 3. Also note the order of these must be Colour00# First and Colour00#_Finding Second

Comment: Yes, that is the nature of CROSSTAB. Review the Allen Brown link some more. You can set up query to force as many columns as you might ever expect (255 column limit in any query). You can use * in SELECT: `SELECT Products.ProductID, ProductName, Query1.*, Query2.* ...` but then column order will not be as you want. Or revisit my UNION then CROSSTAB approach. The only other alternative is a lot of VBA writing data to a 'temp' table (table is permanent but data is temporary). I have used that approach as well.

Comment: Can you please take a look my updated post, using the nested query I am not able to the expected result.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I am learning quite a bit from this