# DataType Mismatch on UnionQuery | MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Essentially I have the following Union Query:

```
SELECT ID, ProductID, AssignedColour AS D, "Assigned" AS Cat, "Colour" & DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID=" & ProductID & " AND ID<" & ID)+1 AS GrpSeq FROM ProductColor
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, ColourFinding, "Finding", "Colour" & DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID=" & ProductID & " AND ID<" & ID)+1 & "_Capacity" FROM ProductColor;
```

Based on the following Table:
[image]

The issue I am having is ProductID was changed from a DataType Number to DataType Short Text.

After the change I get the following error:
DataType Mismatch.

How can the above query be modified to account for this change?

Comment: Use apostrophe delimiters. Answered in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615443/cross-tab-query-with-records-going-horizontally-ms-access/62615623?noredirect=1#comment110749989_62615623

Comment: Why change to text? If every value has "A" prefix, why bother saving that? Or does the letter prefix vary?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    ProductID, 
    AssignedColour AS D, 
    "Assigned" AS Cat, 
    "Colour" & CStr(DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID = '" & ProductID & "' AND ID < " & ID & "") + 1) AS GrpSeq 
FROM 
    ProductColor
UNION 
SELECT 
    ID, 
    ProductID, 
    ColourFinding, 
    "Finding", 
    "Colour" & CStr(DCount("*","ProductColor","ProductID = '" & ProductID & "' AND ID < " & ID & "") + 1) & "_Capacity" 
FROM 
    ProductColor;
```

Comment: This question is part of the larger question that I am still struggling with, do you mind taking a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615443/cross-tab-query-with-records-going-horizontally-ms-access/62615623?noredirect=1#comment110750167_62615623

Comment: @June7 seems to have solved that question in full, and this I have answered, so you should be a bit more detailed about what your issue is. If it is the column count, you can fix that in the `PIVOT` clause if the column count is static; if is is dynamic, you must adjust the SQL of the query.