# Nested Query for filtering a Main query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that shows the net cost and selling cost depending on the weight.
The Slab of the rates are from Min, -45, +45, 100, 300, 500, 1000, Pivot

I created 8 queries to filter a different Slab of the table for example the query of Min is as below

```
SELECT RateAirlineSlabTable.RateAirlineid, RateAirlineSlabTable.RateSlab, RateAirlineSlabTable.NetRate, RateAirlineSlabTable.SellingRate 
FROM RateAirlineSlabTable 
WHERE (((RateAirlineSlabTable.RateSlab)="Min"));
```

Then to be able to show the slab in different columns I created a query that depends on these other 8 queries as below

```
SELECT RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID, RateMinQuery.NetRate AS MinNR, RateMinQuery.SellingRate AS MinSR, [Rate-45Query].NetRate AS [-45NR], [Rate-45Query].SellingRate AS [-45SR], [Rate+45Query].NetRate AS [+45NR], [Rate+45Query].SellingRate AS [+45SR], [Rate+100Query].NetRate AS [+100NR], [Rate+100Query].SellingRate AS [+100SR], [Rate+300Query].NetRate AS [+300], [Rate+300Query].SellingRate AS [+300SR], [Rate+500Query].NetRate AS [+500NR], [Rate+500Query].SellingRate AS [+500SR], [Rate+1000Query].NetRate AS [+1000NR], [Rate+1000Query].SellingRate AS [+1000SR], RatePivotQuery.RateSlab AS [Pivot], RatePivotQuery.NetRate AS PivotNR, RatePivotQuery.SellingRate AS PivotSR 
FROM RatePivotQuery 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate+1000Query] 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate+500Query] 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate+300Query] 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate+100Query] 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate+45Query] 
RIGHT JOIN ([Rate-45Query] 
RIGHT JOIN (RateMinQuery 
RIGHT JOIN RateAirlineTable 
ON RateMinQuery.RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate-45Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate+45Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate+100Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate+300Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate+500Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON [Rate+1000Query].RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID) 
ON RatePivotQuery.RateAirlineid = RateAirlineTable.RateAirlineID;
```

I have being trying to replace the 8 queries in this Main Query, but I cannot make it happen.

Can someone advise me how to do it.

[Actual Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0dgI.png)

[Main Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff8ih.png)

[Desire Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTkYQ.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I already added some pictures, hope they help

Comment: Data should be provided as text tables, not images.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548072/crosstab-query-on-multiple-data-points

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Create a Multi-Value CrossTab Query in Access 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752147/how-can-i-create-a-multi-value-crosstab-query-in-access-2013)

Comment: @GordonLinoff in the following link you can download a sample of my database of what I'm intending to do [link] (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au4uCHYbhednjNJjoMEX_eG965gL9w?e=xEMKVg)

Comment: I check the cross tables but it is not convenient because I have the Pivot column. This range is not always the same. The value will change every time. So if I used a Cross Table will create me a different column for each value and it is not what I want