# MS-Access SQL Pivot multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have a data table that looks like this:

| StreamID | PeriodID | MIN | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STR_01 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| STR_01 | 2 | 0 | 7 |
| STR_01 | 3 | 4 | 9 |
| STR_02 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| STR_02 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| STR_02 | 3 | 0 | 6 |

I'd like to build a pivot table that looks like this:

| StreamID | MIN1 | MIN2 | MIN3 | MAX1 | MAX2 | MAX3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STR_01 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 9 | 7 | 9 |
| STR_02 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 8 | 6 |

How can I do that using SQL language?
Is it possible to pivot directly using more than one field value or do I need to unpivot the original table and create joins with the pivot tables? Is it possible to join pivot tables?
I've tried to unpivot data like this:

| StreamID | PeriodID | Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STR_01 | 1 | MIN | 0 |
| STR_01 | 1 | MAX | 9 |
| STR_01 | 2 | MIN | 0 |
| STR_01 | 2 | MAX | 7 |
| STR_01 | 3 | MIN | 4 |
| STR_01 | 3 | MAX | 9 |

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) *conditional aggregation*. Give it a try and come back with a specific question regarding your earnest attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crosstab Query on multiple data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548072/crosstab-query-on-multiple-data-points). Also review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752147/how-can-i-create-a-multi-value-crosstab-query-in-access-2013

Comment: Conditional aggregation doesn't look that will solve my problem. Although classes (MIN/MAX) are fixed, the number of periods are dynamic. Using Transform and Pivot I can generate a view that contains part of what I want, I mean, in one view I can get all the MIN columns and in other I can get all MAX columns, but I was not able to JOIN these two, at least in MS ACCESS SQL.

Comment: Yes, CROSSTAB queries can be joined. Did you review links provided in previous comment?

Comment: In my MS-Access I cannot join Crosstab Queries. Actually, I cannot do any SQL operation over a crosstab Query. I checked the links above, and I did not find how to do it. If you could give an example of how to do a join between two crosstab queries, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If classes are fixed, and the number of periods are also fixed, the following Query produces your desired result:

```
TRANSFORM First(MinMax)
SELECT StreamID
FROM
(  SELECT StreamID, "MIN" & PeriodID AS Piv, MIN AS MinMax
   FROM Tabla1
 UNION ALL 
   SELECT StreamID, "MAX" & PeriodID AS Piv, MAX AS MinMax
   FROM Tabla1
)
GROUP BY StreamID 
PIVOT Piv 
IN ("MIN1", "MIN2", "MIN3", "MAX1", "MAX2", "MAX3") ;
```

In case the number of periods is dynamic instead of fixed, you just need to remove the "IN" clause, and it will still work, although the order of columns will be determined by the alfanumeric ordering of column names. In this specific case, the "MAX" columns will appear before the "MIN" columns.

You may also want to check the five example queries "F_Transform_..." from the database downloadable from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).

The Query code I provide above can be generalized to a case with more classes (MIN, MAX, MID, ...) as long as the classes are known in advance, just by increasing the number of UNION and SELECT clauses.

Comment: Thanks. Classes are fixed, periods are not. This is the problem. I was able to work around with sub-queries and inner joins, but it's not an elegant solution.
Furthermore, is necessary to remove the ID columns from the other tables after the joins. I'll check you reference.

Comment: The code I provided will work for a dynamic number of periods, just by removing the "IN" clause. The only difference from what you want is that "MAX" columns will appear before "MIN" columns. There is an easy workaround for this of just prefixing "MIN" with "_" so it is ordered ahead of "MAX". Notice that subqueries are somehow inneficcient, so you may want to use my solution above instead of one based on subqueries.